# Remove duplicate names in HTML select box

Tags: jquery, html

How do I remove duplicate names in HTML select box via jQuery.
Here is the fiddle - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/b6fxLnv2/2/)

I tried using -

```
$('select option').each(function() {
  $(this).prevAll('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
});
```

but this only removes duplicate entries when the `option value` are same.

How to I remove duplicates when the text is same but `option values` are different

Answer (score 1):

you can use a array to see if the value is already attribued :

```
label = new Object();
$('select option').each(function(){
    if(label[$(this).text()] != 1)
        label[$(this).text()] = 1;
    else $(this).remove();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6fxLnv2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select option').each(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('option[value="' + this.text + '"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: It would be better that you describe your answer what are differences from question

Comment: he use this.text instead of this.value, but this will not work because the text of an element can't be a part of a selector

Answer (score 0):

```
var $o = $('select option');
$o.filter(function(i, el) {
    return $o.filter(function() { 
              return this.textContent === el.textContent; 
           }).index() !== i;
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msL6yLzd/